# Чтение массива данный из файла через гетеры

Tags: java

Задача: Вывести список всех смартфонов, сгруппированных по производителю. Вопрос: Как прочитать файл так, чтобы все уникальные столбцы(Серийный номер, Производитель, Модель, Операционная система,Объем оперативной памяти) каждой читались отдельно и записались с помощью ArrayList в массив и что бы потом каждую строку можно было пропустить через форму геттеров. Вот форма:

```
public class IntoBox {
        static void p(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        }

        public int number;
        public String maker;
        public String model;
        public String os;
        public int ram;

        public IntoBox (int number, String maker, String model, String os, int ram){
            this.number = number;
            this.maker = maker;
            this.model = model;
            this.os = os;
            this.ram = ram;
            this.i = i;

        }

        //getters
        public int getNumber(){
            return number;
        }
        public String getMaker(){
            return maker;
        }
        public String getModel(){
            return model;
        }
        public String getOs(){
            return os;
        }
        public int getRam(){
            return ram;
        }


        //setters
        public void setNumber(int number){
            this.number=number;
        }
        public void setMaker(String maker){
            this.maker=maker;
        }
        public void setModel(String model){
            this.model=model;
        }
        public void setOs(String os){
            this.os=os;
        }
        public void setRam(int ram){
            this.ram=ram;
        }
```

Пример данных из файла:
1111 Samsung A5 Android 1000
Как я читаю файл:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File inputFile = new File("C:\\data\\data.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

            while (reader.ready()) 
                arrayList.add(reader.readLine());
            reader.close();
```

Comment: ответ - создать парсер файла, который построчно прочитает и разобьет строку на нужные поля и передаст в массив обьекты. Что уже пробовали для этого?

Comment: @xAqweRx, т.е. arrayList.add(reader.readLine(getNumber(),...,getRam())); ?

Comment: Добавьте код парсинга, что бы понять что не так. Одна строка не поможет

Comment: @xAqweRx, понимаете... Я не знаю что такое "парсинг" , я новичок в java.

Comment: парсинг в данном контексте означает - разбор строки по нужным параметрам. Предоставьте в вопросе пример информации из файла  + то как вы читаете файл

Comment: @xAqweRx, я просто не могу реализовать то что я хочу, поэтому тут пишу. Сейчас добавлю пример данных из фала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример того что может работать, но тут куча дыр. Нужно проверить входящие данные и так далее.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    String sCurrentLine;
    String filePath = "filePath";
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( filePath ));
    ArrayList<IntoBox> inboxes = new ArrayList();
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] params = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
        inboxes.add( new IntoBox ( Integer.parseInt( params[0]), params[1], params[2], params[3], Integer.parseInt( params[4])) );
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```